# How do I target the inside of multiple objects

Tags: jquery, html, json

How do I do this: I have a div: `<div data-something""></div>` The data-something contains a json array:

```
{"question":[{"id":1,"question":"Ducimus aperiam nesciunt est quia."},{"id":2,"question":"Minima sunt qui similique ut culpa natus consequatur."},{"id":3,"question":"Sit et nihil ut porro amet laborum iure molestiae."},{"id":4,"question":"Dolore quaerat molestiae iste in dolores harum rerum."},{"id":5,"question":"Quia quasi quae sint saepe."},{"id":6,"question":"Tempora et quo aperiam natus."}]}
```

I want to use the data inside with jQuery. I put the data inside a jquery var.

```
var test = $("#target").data("something");
```

Here I am stuck. How can I get, for example, the question from id:4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is convert the string to an array and access it by index as below:

```
var test = $("#target").data("something");
var test_array = JSON.parse(test);
```

because it is converted to an array you can use id - 1 so to get question with id 4 it is sub 3 assuming that your id are in order

```
var Q4 = test_array ['question'][3]['question'];
console.log (Q4);
```

If not then you can use a for loop and check the id as below:

```
for (sub in test_array ['question'] ) {
    if (4 == test_array ['question'][sub]['id'])
        var Q4 = test_array ['question'][sub]['question'];

console.log (Q4);
```

Comment: I have tried this approach before, but got an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: That is bcause you probably had an invalid json or in your code you have it adding an 'o' without knowing. I had just tried it with your string and it work..

Comment: var json = '{"question":[{"id":1,"question":"Ducimus aperiam nesciunt est quia."},{"id":2,"question":"Minima sunt qui similique ut culpa natus consequatur."},{"id":3,"question":"Sit et nihil ut porro amet laborum iure molestiae."},{"id":4,"question":"Dolore quaerat molestiae iste in dolores harum rerum."},{"id":5,"question":"Quia quasi quae sint saepe."},{"id":6,"question":"Tempora et quo aperiam natus."}]}';

Comment: if not the try using `var test = $("#target").attr("data-something");`.  It should not make a difference but its worth a shot

If not send me what you have and Ill help :)

Comment: No problem ^_^ Glad I can help

Answer (score 0):

also you can refer to id with this way

```js
var infos = '{"questions":['+
   '{ "id":1, "question":"Ducimus aperiam nesciunt est quia." },'+
   '{ "id":2, "question":"Minima sunt qui similique ut culpa natus consequatur." },'+
   '{  "id":3, "question":"Sit et nihil ut porro amet laborum iure molestiae."    },'+
   '{ "id":4, "question":"Dolore quaerat molestiae iste in dolores harum rerum." },'+
   '{ "id":5, "question":"Quia quasi quae sint saepe." },'+
   '{ "id":6, "question":"Tempora et quo aperiam natus."}'+
   ']}';

   
   var x = function (a,b) {

    obj = JSON.parse(b);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Question:"+obj.questions[a].id+"<br>"+obj.questions[a].question+"<br>";
   
   };

   var z = x(3,infos);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var test = $("#target").data("something"), obj = JSON.parse(test);
      console.log(obj);
});
```

Write this and show your console, your json is now an object and you can use as an object. For example: `obj.question[0].question` show you in console: "`Ducimus aperiam nesciunt est quia.`".

Probabily you have that error because your html is like this:

`<div id="test" data-something="{"json"}">`

and "" inside "" is not good use this:

```
<div id="test" data-something='{"json"}'>
```